# Custom cells in UITableView become blank after scrolling up or down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I was tasked to solve this bug in the app (It's for comercial use so I can't link the project). I'm also completely new to Objective-C or IOS development and I have no idea why the following happens. Reminder, I'm using custom cells.

When the tableview loads, everything looks fine.
[Click here to see the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kulvh.png)

But when I scroll up and back to the same postion the cell becomes blank, as if it had no data. [Blank cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waqWP.png)

If I repeat the same process everything looks fine again.

Here's the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    
    
    static NSString *cellId = @"cell2";
    PedTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [(PedTableCell*)[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
        
    }
    if (tableView==_table3)
    {
        
        NSString *docsDirr;
        NSString *documentsDirectoryForSaveImages;
        docsDirr = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
        documentsDirectoryForSaveImages = [docsDirr stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/CarpetaImatges"];
        
        
        
        NSString *match = @".jpg";
        NSString *preCodigo;
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[pedarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [scanner scanUpToString:match intoString:&preCodigo];

        NSString *nomimg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", preCodigo];
        
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[documentsDirectoryForSaveImages stringByAppendingPathComponent:nomimg]];
        
        cell.img.image = img;
        cell.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
        cell.img.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
        
        
        
        
        cell.cart.text = preCodigo;
        cell.descart.text = [nomarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.cant.text = [cantarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.precart.text = [precioarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.pvpcart.text = [pvparray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        [cell layoutIfNeeded];
        
    }
    return cell;
    
}
```

I've debugged the method and everytime it returns a valid cell. When I click the empty cell it still works as expected. Essentially, the data is there, it's just not rendered for some reason.

I've checked other posts with the same/similar issue but nothing seems to really match. PrepareForReuse is a no go since there's no UI to be changed, just content. I'm getting the values of the arrays with indexPath.row to make sure I'm fetching the correct value. I've even tried to set the heightForRowAtIndexPath to the same height the cell should have (all cells are of the same size and never change) or let AutoLayout handle it but to no avail.

Code of numberOfRowsInSection (Returns the amount of orders that exists in database currently):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(tableView == _table3)
    {
        [self cargacarro];
        
        return pedarray.count;
        
    }
    return pedarray.count;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The table view cell data depend on nomarray, cantarray, precioarray, pvparray?  I am afraid that the code shown in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method does not make sense.  What does the `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate method return, then?

Comment: @ElTomato numberOfRowsInSection returns the count value of pedarray.

Comment: Then you should stick to pedarray in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method when you set the table cell data.

Comment: @ElTomato Here's the thing, on cargaCarro, objects from the database are retrieved, but values are saved into different arrays, pedarrays has all order codes, precioarray all prices, etc. Pedarray[0]: "Order 1" precioarray[0]: "price of Order 1", etc. The important thing is the row index, and as I said, the loaded data is correct and matches the expected values, it's just not rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your cell nib in storyboard or in code before tableview is loaded, and after replace `dequeueReusableCell...` with this one

```
PedTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.img... 
cell.cart...
```

remove this part, is no longer needed

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [(PedTableCell*)[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
}
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer cause it actually solved my issue. I had to figure out that i needed a .xib file first, but now instead of displaying the data it's just displaying the name i've given the labels. Did I forget to set something on the xib?

Comment: Here `cell = [(PedTableCell*)[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];` you alloc a new cell with default style, which is not your cell, it's a default one, you need to register your nib if you are using .xib or to add it directly in tableview if you are using storyboard, and after that just call `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];` and it will return your cell.

Comment: I had forgotten to link the outlets of the xib to the .h properties. Now everything works wonderfully. Thanks for the help!